# Can't figure out why this algorithm is updating all fields in an arraylist

Tags: java, swing, algorithm, jtable, cellrenderer

I have a JTable cell that displays a checkbox and JLabel, which tracks the amount of time that that checkbox is checked for. The problem is that when I add multiple rows and check one row every row begins counting, rather than only the one selected.

It seems like my code is ignoring the row specific if statements. I'm lost as to why.

This is the algorithm in the table model. It is called every second when on a timer event.

```
public void updateTime()
    {
        Date newTime = new Date();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.startTime.size(); i++)
            {

                if (data.getVisible(i).selected == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("updateTime");
                    System.out.println(i);

                    String value = df.format(new Date(newTime.getTime() - data.rowList.get(i).startTime));
                    data.setVisible(i, value);
                }
                else if (data.getVisible(i).selected == false)
                    data.setVisible(i, new String("00:00"));

                fireTableRowsUpdated(i,i);
            }  
    }
```

This is the code in the data model

```
public void setVisible(int index, Object newVar)
       {
           //System.out.println(index);


           if (newVar.getClass() == Boolean.class)
           {
               if ((Boolean) newVar)
               {
                    Value newValue = new Value(new Boolean(true), visible.get(index).value);

                    rowList.remove(index);
                    Row aRow = new Row((Boolean)newVar, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    rowList.add(index, aRow);

                    visible.remove(index);
                    visible.add(index, newValue);
               }
               else if ((Boolean) newVar == false)
               {

                    rowList.remove(index);
                    Row aRow = new Row(new Boolean(false), new Long(0));
                    rowList.add(index, aRow);
                    System.out.println("VALUE OF ROWLIST");
                    for (int i = 0; i < rowList.size(); i++)
                    {
                    System.out.println(rowList.get(i).startTime);
                    }

                    Value newValue = new Value((Boolean)newVar, "");

                    visible.remove(index);
                    visible.add(index, newValue);
               }
               }
               else if (newVar.getClass() == String.class)
               {
                   Value newValue = new Value(visible.get(index).selected, newVar.toString());

                   visible.remove(index);
                   visible.add(index, newValue);
               }
```

This is the cell renderer

```
public class CheckboxCellRenderer extends JCheckBox
    implements TableCellRenderer {

    TableCellRenderer delegate;

    public CheckboxCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer defaultRenderer){
    this.delegate = defaultRenderer;
    }

    public CheckboxCellRenderer(){

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

        Value v = (Value) value;
        this.setSelected(v.selected);
        if (v.selected)
        this.setText(v.value);
        if (isSelected) {
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

and the value class

```
public class Value implements Comparable<Value> {

    public Boolean selected;
    public String value;

    public Value(Boolean selected, String value) {
        this.selected = selected;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Value v) {
        return this.value.compareTo(v.value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object v) {
        return v instanceof Value && this.value.equals(((Value) v).value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.value.hashCode();
    }
}
```

value editor

```
public class ValueEditor extends AbstractCellEditor
    implements TableCellEditor, ItemListener {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

    private CheckboxCellRenderer vr = new CheckboxCellRenderer();

    public ValueEditor() {
        vr.addItemListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return vr.isSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int col) {
        Value v = (Value) value;
        vr.setSelected(v.selected);
        if (!v.selected)
            vr.setText("00:00");
        else
            vr.setText(v.value);
        return vr;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        this.fireEditingStopped();
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        } 
        else 
        {
            vr.setText("00:00");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really consider shorten your question and your code to focus on what you want and what the problem is. SO is not a code review platform...

Comment: Also, fixing your indentation would be great - I got mixed up in a few different spots just trying to figure out what was going on.

Comment: In your aetVisible method, you're remove elements from a collection and reinserting them at a given index, you might consider using set instead to update the value, if available

Comment: Remember that the renderer is reused for each visible cell; your timer handler should check the _model_ for the `Boolean` value that's rendered with a checkbox.